# If f(x) and g(x) are increasing functions, which functions might be non-increasing?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

If f(x) and g(x) are increasing functions, which two of these functions might not be increasing?

$$f(x)+g(x); \ f(x)*g(x); \  f(g(x)); \ f^{-1}(x); \  \frac{1}{f(x)}$$

The answer given is $f(x)*g(x)$ and $\frac{1}{f(x)}$. However, I feel only $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is non increasing. I doubt f(x) * g(x) is non-increasing too. The following is my justification:

> Suppose $f(x) = m$ and $g(x) = n$, then $f(x)*g(x) = m*n$. If $y > x$, then by the premises $f(y) > m$. Similarly, if $y > x$, then $g(y) > n$. So, $f(y)*g(y) >m*n = f(x) * g(x)$. Thus, if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are increasing functions, then $f(x)*g(x)$ should also increasing function.

Is my justification correct? Can someone please give me a counterexample if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Let $f=g$ be the identity, they're increasing functions. We have $-2<-1$, but $f(-2)g(-2)=4>1=f(-1)g(-1)$

Comment: For the product, if $x>0$, consider $f(x)=g(x)=-\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}$. Clearly is increasing, but the product $f(x)=g(x)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{x^2}$ is decreasing if $x>0$.

Comment: Try using the chain rule on each expression and discuss when the derivatives of those expressions are positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)= -\exp(-x)$$ is an increasing function

$$g(x)=x$$ is another increasing function.

However, their product is not an increasing function

[image]

I think you have not taken care of negative numbers in your argument.